# How to aggregate values inside a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, pivot

I could not solve this question, any help?

Batsman_detail table has the columns ,
[Opposition (varchar), runs(int), dismissal(varchar), venue(varchar)]:

- `opposition` column has may countries in it.
- `runs` column has the amount of runs scored by the batsman in that match.
- `dimissal` column has any of the following values caught/bowled/run out/not out.
- `venue` column has the stadium name where the match is held.

Now you should write a query such that the output table must have that number of times the batsman had gone out in a type of dismissal against the countries Pakistan,Australia and Srilanka (Original table contains many countries.),

Example output format :

```
opposition                caught     bowled      runout      notout    
Pakistan                  3              5               7               9   
Australia                 0              4               4               1    
Sri Lanka                 4              2               3               4
```

Comment: *Now you should write a query ...* We ???

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ...that said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select opposition,
    sum(case when dismissal = 'caught'  then runs else 0 end) caught,
    sum(case when dismissal = 'bowled'  then runs else 0 end) bowled,
    sum(case when dismissal = 'run out' then runs else 0 end) run_out,
    sum(case when dismissal = 'not out' then runs else 0 end) not_out
from batsman
group by opposition
```

This sums the `runs` for each value of `dismissal`. If you just want to count the occurences, then:

```
select opposition,
    sum(dismissal = 'caught')  caught,
    sum(dismissal = 'bowled')  bowled,
    sum(dismissal = 'run out') run_out,
    sum(dismissal = 'not out') not_out
from batsman
group by opposition
```

Answer (score 1):

You can distinctly select all dismissal cases and then pivot dynamically as

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM(CASE WHEN dismissal =''', dismissal, ''' THEN runs ELSE 0 END ) AS ',
                     dismissal
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT dismissal
           FROM Batsman_detail 
       ) b;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT opposition,',@sql,
                   ' FROM Batsman_detail
                    GROUP BY opposition'); 


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=40c79fffe2a18746a09ab0efa8b31b4b)</kbd>